# What's the quickest way to defog a windshield?

Tags: hvac, windshield

For a properly functioning auto, what's the quickest way to defog the windshield?  There are lots of air control options - hot vs. cold air, exterior vs. recirculated air - but which are the most effective (assuming the auto is functioning correctly)?

Comment: You've been asking quite a few foggy window questions. Does your car have air conditioning?

Comment: Yup.(I figured that both of these were different questions.)

Comment: Yes they are certainly different questions, I'm just wondering what the root cause is of all your fog. Let us know when it started, if it happens during a certain time of day, are there any strange engine noises?

Comment: @hillsons - The root cause of my fog is a heater core leak (details in other question) as diagnosed by the shop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will depend on your car, the outdoors humidity, the air temperature and the engine temperature. As an example, for me on a cold icy morning starting with a cold engine:

- aircon on
- fan on low
- use external air, not recirculator!
- front windscreen demister (covers wiper rest area)
- rev engine until at working temp
- then put fan on high

But in high humidity areas in the summer I would use:

- aircon on
- fan on high
- use recirculator

Comment: Just to be clear, you use air conditioning on cold icy mornings?

Comment: Definitely - it dries the air very quickly. Without it I have to wait until the turbo heats up to properly dry incoming air. The air still won't be warm for the first few minutes, but at least it is dehumidifying.

Comment: Interesting, where I live the humidity in the air is so low during the winter that I typically don't worry about that.  I just worry about frost and ice on the windshield. :)

Comment: Heh - this is Scotland :-)

Answer (score 4):

Hot air from the exterior with your a/c on is the quickest. Though in general having the a/c on is the most important piece, as it removes moisture from the air.

Answer (score 1):

My old Fiat Marea Weekend had instructions for defogging the windshield on the inside of the driver's visor:

> - Turn the blower on max
> - Turn the heat on max
> - Turn the recirculation off
> - Put down the visors

I was wondering about that last bit, so I've asked a follow-up:

[Does putting down the visors help defogging the windshield?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/39997/14105)